Problema no VS 2022
Olá, boa tarde. Tentei criar um projeto Blazor web app no visual studio 2022 e ele cria o projeto sem nada dentro
Ja tentei reparar, instalar tudo possivel e ate desinstalei e reinstalei o VS, mas nada funcionou aqui está a imagem

Ola,
Tente clonar um projeto já existe.
Ou tente abrir pela pasta onde criou.
